# Angular Component Based CSS

Tags: angular

In Angular 4/5, is there a way that component based will be generated to a file instead of **style** tag.

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['../../assets/css/auth.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    providers: [AuthenticationService]
})
```

Only files under angular-cli.json styles were generated to a file.

```
"prefix": "app",
 "styles": [               
   "../src/assets/css/bootstrap.min.scss",
   "../src/assets/fonts/fontface.min.scss",                
   "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css", 
   "app/chronos/assets/css/main.scss"
 ]
```

Here is what I am using:

- "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.1"
- "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.1"
- "@angular/core": "^5.0.1"
- "@angular/forms": "^5.0.1"

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to remove the stylesheet from the styleUrls property in your component and either add it to the styles property in angular-cli.json or add it to a top-level css file referenced from your index html file.

Comment: I don't want to make it global as it is only for that specific component.

Comment: Understood. In Angular 2/4, anything added to the styles property in .angular-cli.json will be compiled into the styles bundle and applied to your html elements inline. I'm not sure of any way to get around that if you are referring to the CSS from your component. Adding to a global CSS file is an alternative, you can also add to to a CSS file with selectors specific to your component but you'd still need to append it to your HTML through some means, and it would become tedious to use separate CSS files in this manner for each component.

Comment: You can also try to segregate the styles in a more global CSS by starting your selectors from the component's selector, something like 'my-login-component .xyz' in your example (if you were to specify a selector: 'my-login-component' property in your component's decorator.

Comment: Yes I understand. Everytime I am running the application all the css specified in the components are generated in the index.html and placed under **style** tag. I am wondering how caching will take effect with this setup. As we all know, for the syle bundle, it will generate new hash everytime there is a changes with any of the files in the angular-cli. With this, problem with caching is not happening.

Comment: Right, as long the update to your index.html file is seen in the browser (not cached), the newly generated styles bundle, with new hash in the filename, should be retrieved. If you were to use a more global CSS file, you'd need to add some sort of cache-busting technique. There are many strategies to accomplish that. The can be found with a simple web search.